# Error: Could not find or load main class- Novice

Tags: java, exception, file-not-found

Hi I am a novice in JAVA. I have been getting this file not found exception inspite of the file existing in the very location I have specified in the path which is

Initially I had the issue of file not found. However, after performing a clean and re-run, now I am having an issue which says

> Error: Could not find or load main class main.main

```
import Message.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class main{  


public static void main(String[] args) {

        Message msg=new Message("bob","alice","request","Data@@@@");
        MPasser passerObj=new MPasser("C:\\Workspace\\config.txt","process1");

    }
}
```

Also in the MPasser Constructor the following piece of relevant code is there

```
public class MPasser(String file_name,String someVariable){
    InputStream input;
        try {
            input =new RandomAccessFile(file_name,"r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
            }
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    Map<String, String> Object = (Map<String, String>) yaml.load(input);
}
```

Sorry I have made edits from initial query so that it is more clear

Comment: why does your constructor has a `Class` keyword associated with it

Comment: You should respect the case: `public` not `Public` and `class` if that's the class definition (although you're talking about a constructor here). Shouldn't that be `"r"` instead of `'r'` too? (As others have said, you're also missing `new`.)

Comment: @Bruno "r" is taken care off, but the issue persists. The point to be noted here is the fact that, it shows error in 11th line in the main() function where there is actually no line of code as such. I presume you are talking about the new for the `new RandomAccessFile(file_name,"r");` That is also not helping

Comment: The fact that this 11th line (where the exception is thrown) is somewhere where there is no code could indicate that you're not actually running a version of the code compiled from your latest source file. Hard to say, but since you seem to indicate you're a novice, could you double check?

Comment: @Bruno I did clean and run the file. Now I have a new error. The file  not found exception is gone but a new exception Error: Could not find or load main class main

Comment: Just a suggestion you should not name your class `public class main` main.Always use names which signify the purpose of your code.

Comment: @RanRag do you think it could be a naming issue? I tried changing the name into something else and still the error persists

Comment: No its not a naming issue. I just gave a naming convention related suggestion.

Comment: @RanRag yeah I do understand that. Thanks for the constructive suggestion :)

Comment: I believe your `message` and `main` class are not in the same folder.Am i right.

Comment: @RanRag yes. They are two different packages under the same src folder

Comment: have you compiled your message and MPasser class.

Comment: @RanRag Yes I have. There is no issue with that so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
input = RandomAccessFile("C:\Workspace\conf.txt",'r');
```

You need to escape the `\`'s

```
input = RandomAccessFile("C:\\Workspace\\conf.txt",'r');
```

Comment: Hi I did Try that but no success :(

Comment: Are you missing the `new` keyword as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
 "C:\Workspace\conf.txt"
```

Those are escape sequences. You probably meant:

```
 "C:\\Workspace\\conf.txt"
```

You also appear to call it `config.txt` in one snippet and `conf.txt` in the other?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the java process has permissions to read the file.

Comment: Can u have a look at the revised issue and suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslash.

```
input = RandomAccessFile("C:\\Workspace\\conf.txt",'r');
```

and also

```
 input = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Workspace\\conf.txt",'r');
```

and why you have two different filename `conf.txt` and `config.txt`.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have edited my initial query.. While pasting the code I somehow happened to erase it. Apologies