# Could not find or load main class SDK -jar

Tags: java, android, jar

**Objective** 
-I want to run an open source java project jar i.e https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples/releases which I need for my host card emulation android project.

I'm referring to this [example](http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/07/android-host-card-emulation-with-acr122/) for running the this java jar project

```
java -cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo
```

But I'm getting **error** **-Could not find or load main class SDK**

**I also tried the command with complete path**

```
java -cp C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples.jar C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples\org\nfctools\examples\hce\org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo
```

I have gone through the following links but did not find a solution

["Error: Could not find or load main class My.class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473854/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-my-class)

[Error: Could not find or load main class- Novice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966266/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-novice)

[Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

My java version is 1.7.0

I have not worked much with java projects, please help!

**EDIT**

Path of the nfctools-examples.jar is C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0

[image]

**Commands used**

```
C:\Users\sony>java -cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo  
Error: Could not find or load main class org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo                                                                                      
C:\Users\sony>cd C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples\org\nfctools   
                                                                                                                                 C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples\org\nfctools>java -cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo                           
Error: Could not find or load main class org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo 

C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples\org\nfctools>java -cp C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo                                                                         
Error: Could not find or load main class SDK
```

Comment: `java -cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo` for this does this jar file exist in  CWD? does this class exist in that jar file  ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java is java path and the path variable is also set.I tried the command with & without setting the CWD (with cd cmd) to pat where the jar is located

Comment: no I meant where is this jar located related to your current working directory ?

Comment: My first thought is that there's no manifest in the executable JAR to say what the main class is.

Comment: @JigarJoshi pls see my edit , I have mentioned the path of jar and the commands I used

Comment: your screenshot is not friendly, could you copy and paste the content instead ?

Comment: or `C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0` go to this directory by `cd` and then invoke `java -cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo`

Comment: @duffymo there is an MAnifest.mf file at path nfctools-examples\META-INF  I'll paste the commands aswell .thanks

Comment: @duffymo i don't think there should be a manifest to say which is the main class, as the command contains the main class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this should work for you:

```
java -cp "C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples.jar" org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo
```

first problem was jar not in current directory,

second issue is space in jar path, you should use " when the path have space.

third, you should not append full path before the main class name, just `package.name.className`